# Django AutoField: does it create db_index on itself?

Tags: django, django-models

Question is: does Django [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) create db_index on itself? *(In docs I didn't find anything about that)*

If not, how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can run `python manage.py sqlindexes __your_app__` to check the indexes that `syncdb` will create.

Comment: I've checked, but there is no index for `id` field.

Answer (score 3):

An `AutoField` must have `primary_key=True`. A primary key is a unique index.

Comment: By default Django applies `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) however in postgres id fields do not appear to be indexed.

Comment: @alias51 see the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS): *Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will force the column(s) to be marked NOT NULL.*

Comment: Thanks. Am I misreading PGAdmin in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164377/does-django-index-autofield-id-keys-in-postgresql). I.e. does the primary key shown also infer the index? I am confused as I would expect an index to also be shown?

Comment: I've left an answer to your question - it appears that PGAdmin does not show the automatic primary key indexes.