# Does Django index Autofield / ID keys in PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Django's docs state that `id` fields created with `AutoField` [are indexed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> id is indexed by the database and is guaranteed to be unique.

Similarly it applies an index to every FK relationship.

However, in PostgreSQL whilst FKs appear to be indexed, IDs are not. Here's an example:

```
class TestModelBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fkfield = models.ForeignKey(TestModelFK, blank=True, null=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    m2mfield = models.ManyToManyField(TestModelM2M, related_name='base_m2m')
```

This model appears to apply the `fkfield` index, but not the `id` autofield. From PGAdmin below:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL automatically creates indexes for primary keys. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS):

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will force the column(s) to be marked NOT NULL.

It appears that PGAdmin does not show those indexes. [This mailing list thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/03AF4E498C591348A42FC93DEA9661B889F234%40mail.vale-housing.co.uk) is the best source I could find.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that django + postgres will still let you manually create an index on a primary key (e.g. `indexes = [models.Index(fields=['id'], name='%(class)s_id_idx'),]` ). I would have thought it would reject the duplicate?

Comment: Postgres allows multiple indexes on the same field so Django should as well. It might be useful if Django had a [system check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/checks/#database) to warn about it.